# Elastichsearch: request [/someindex/_refresh] contains unrecognized parameter: [refresh]

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa, elasticsearch-jest

I have a problem on local machine with elastic search refresh. I use Spring data JPA and when I save document I got an exception:

```
Error during managed flush [Cannot execute jest action , response code : 400 , error : {"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [/videostatistics/_refresh] contains unrecognized parameter: [refresh]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [/videostatistics/_refresh] contains unrecognized parameter: [refresh]"} , message : null]
```

Local and remote versions are the same: 5.1.2

The url format looks like: `http://localhost:9200/videostatistics/_refresh?refresh=true`

Answer (score 1):

I solved problem by installing version 2.4.5.
But I still confused why version 5.1.2 is working on remote on searchly.com

If there any suggestion please provide.

Answer (score 0):

The client seems to send a parameter, that is not supported by Elasticsearch. In Elasticsearch 5.x adding unused parameters leads to an exception, which was not the case in 2.4.

To fix this, your client should not sent that parameter on refresh.